# Is there any way to add input values to python configparser config properties? SOLVED

Tags: python, json, configuration, yaml, configparser

I'm going to try to add some values to my config file, but I've got a traceback error what is KeyError.
Here's the config

```
property=input("Please add property's value here")
config['sectionuniqeid']={'property':value1,'property2':value2,'property':value3}
```

And are there any way to make a variable unique?

Comment: We can't reproduce what you're doing with just those two lines of code, please add the whole code needed to reproduce the problem. Also please don't just spam tags; your file is either JSON or YAML or that ConfigParser-INI-thing, but not everything at once.

Comment: Solved.
"""
cfg=ConfigParser()
property=input('Add the property name')
property2=input('Add the property name')
property3=input('Add the property name')
cfg[property]={'property2':property2,{'property3':property3}

with open('filename.cfg','a') as configfile:
cfg.write(configfile)"""